# How to remove default icon at the top of next.js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have tried as of all I know

1. Deleted cached
2. Changed the icon to the one I wanted

   Whatever image I am replacing with favicon.ico it is changing to the previous icon and shows the default

   Help!!!

I am expecting to add icon of my own

Comment: what nextjs version?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you can remove the default favicon.ico, and add a icon.png at /app folder. You can use either the name favicon or icon, custom file names are not allowed. Next.js will evaluate the file and automatically add the appropriate tags to your app's  element.

You can see the nextjs document for more details https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/app-icons#image-files-ico-jpg-png

Answer (score 0):

To change the favicon in your next app, you'll have to replace the default icon with the new favicon you want. This will mean the new icon will have `favicon.ico` containing your new icon.

After correctly replacing it, you must *empty cache and hard reload* for it to take effect as so:

[image]

The steps to reproduce:

1. Enter inspect elements
2. Right-click on the reload button at top left of the screen (you'll see the three options as seen in the picture)
3. Click the third option

Answer (score 0):

This can happen **when the file name is the same as before.**

### Potential Solutions:

1. Try a new file name, such as changing favicon.ico to favicontwo.ico
   and update the link: `<link rel="icon" href="/favicontwo.ico" />`
2. Try forcing an update to the icon by adding a version: `<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico?v=2" />` which forces the browser to
   fetch the file again
3. Check file type, make sure the icon is a .ico type, which all modern browsers can handle. You can also add a type option: `<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`

Answer (score 0):

try to put this inside of your root layout and it will work

```
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  icons: {
    icon: [
      {
        url: "/images/favicon.png",
        href: "/images/favicon.png",
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

update the URL and href as your file path and extension.

Answer (score 0):

I just used another browser, and after restarting the system, it worked.
The simplest explanation is always almost the right answer